# Incompatibility between mdframed and todonotes?

Tags: incompatibility, mdframed, todonotes

Is there an incompatibility between `mdframed` and `todonotes`? For example, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  x\todo{y}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Is there a trick to avoid it?

Comment: Your sample code is missing `\usepackage{todonotes}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thx! Added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`todonotes` uses `\marginpar` which is a floating object and `mdframed` doesn't allow floats; you can use the `inline` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  x\todo[inline]{y}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package, instead of `\marginpar` in the internal `\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.75ex]%
    \node [coordinate] (inText) {};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\marginnote[{% Draw note in left margin
    \@todonotes@drawMarginNote%
    \@todonotes@drawLineToLeftMargin%
}]{% Draw note in right margin
    \@todonotes@drawMarginNote%
    \@todonotes@drawLineToRightMargin%
}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  x\todo{y}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]